# Comparing an Arraylist in a List with other Arraylists within the same list

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have been trying to no avail to find a solution to this thing i am trying to do. What i am trying to do is to check if the String superConcept is equal to the first element of a line within the kb, and if so, it is checked if any of the remaining Arraylists in the list contain the same first element.

```java
public static List<ArrayList<String>> kb = new ArrayList<>();

for(ArrayList<String> line : kb){
    if(superConcept.equals(line.get(0))){
        //to check if there are any other lines within the kb that contain the same first element (line.get(0))
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: So you want to figure out which arraylists contain `superConcept` as their first element?

Comment: yes, within that loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> targetLists = new ArrayList<>();

for (ArrayList<String> list : kb)
    if (list.size() > 0 && list.get(0).equals(superConcept))
        targetLists.add(list);
```

Comment: how would i go about clearing everything in targetList after i am done with the iteration, so that i would have targetLists fresh when the next iteration starts?

Comment: What iteration? Just create a new one everytime you call this piece of code, or, if you want to make it a global variable, call `targetLists.clear()` before the loop.